# Where can I find protective sleeves for my Dixit cards?

Tags: game-accessories, dixit

I'm afraid my Dixit cards will get worn or marked over time. I want players to be able to manipulate them without being afraid of ruining them.

**Where can I find protective sleeves for my Dixit cards?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mayday Games](http://maydaygames.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=magnum&x=0&y=0) has 80 x 120 mm in stock which is what you need.

I'm told that 3 x 5 recipe card covers will work as well.  You can find them on Amazon if you can't find them locally.

Answer (score 3):

Board Game Geek has a listing of the card's size and the various types of sleeves that will fit them

http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/102880/item/1981056#item1981056

> Number of Cards: 84
>
> Mayday Sleeve Size: Magnum Gold 80 x 120 mm
>
> Swan Panasia Sleeve Size: SWN-045 (Dixit) 80 x 120 mm